# SoftLayer API - How to get Volume Id out of the json response from the ordering part

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have Ansible playbook for ordering Portable Storage. How can I extract/get to the Volume Id from that order json response so I can use it later in next tasks for attaching to the instance?
I understand I have placed an order and it must be approved first. In my case it takes little or no time and gets approved right away. I would like to create and attach the volume in one ansible play.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As the portable storage needs to be approved, the response of the order does not contains the id of the newly created portal storage, however the response contains the property called "orderId" using the value of this property you can get the portable storage. For example using a REST request like this:

```
GET https://$USERNAME:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getPortableStorageVolumes?objectFilter={"portableStorageVolumes": {"billingItem":{"orderItem":{"order":{"id":{"operation": $ORDERID}}}}}}

Note: Replace $USERNAME $APIKEY $ORDERID
```

In order to make it work using curl you need to encode the URL e.g.

```
curl -X GET -u $USERNAME:$APIKEY https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getPortableStorageVolumes?objectFilter=%7B%22portableStorageVolumes%22%3A+%7B%22billingItem%22%3A%7B%22orderItem%22%3A%7B%22order%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%7B%22operation%22%3A+$ORDERID%7D%7D%7D%7D%7D%7D

Note: Replace $USERNAME $APIKEY $ORDERID
```

The request above will return only the newly created portable storage, so you can get from the json the id of the portable storage to perform other tasks with it.

Regards

Comment: I have tested it in Postman and works great. I have found the missing information. Now moving forward to console - Is there any way to use objectFilter in curl or ansible uri module and pass the parameters in json body for the GET method?